# How do I remove bottom padding on image/content on jQuery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am not sure whether the padding on the bottom (look for the red pixels below the photo) is set on the image, or on the content div, but I want to get rid of it. A jsFiddle of my issue is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FERUs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display: block to your images css:

```
#picture {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    display: block;
}
```

More info [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/247615-annoying-white-space-under-an-image/).